# How to set the Background color animation in Silver light and WinRT in code behind?

Tags: silverlight, winrt-xaml

In WPF we can animate the back ground color for the particular control by using below code:
`AssociatedObject.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ColorAnimation);`
But I don't know how to animate the same in Silverlight and WinRT platforms.

Comment: Please answer this question.

Comment: Could you please suggest me how to set the animation in WinRT in code behind

Answer (score 0):

The WPF code is (I think?) a shorthand for creating a storyboard, adding an animation and assigning its target, and running the storyboard.  You can do the same in Silverlight like this:

```
var animation = new ColorAnimation 
{
    To = Colors.Black,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
};

Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, AssociatedObject.Background);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));

var sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(animation);
sb.Begin();
```

Comment: I tried this but i got the exception "Element is already the child of another element". how can achieve my requirement.

Comment: If i set the DataContext for that particular control i got the exception."Operation is not valid on an active Animation or Storyboard.  Root Storyboard must be stopped first." Could you please help me how can i solve this problem and achieve my requirement.